# How can I detect Novo button power-up in GRUB 2 on a Lenovo G550 laptop?

Tags: boot, grub, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo G550 laptop has [an alternative power-on button next to the normal power button](https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/lenovo_g550_onetouchrecovery01_02.jpg) (called the ‘Novo button’) that is apparently meant to trigger an alternative booting mode into recovery partition.  On my machine, it seems to just start the ordinary boot process.  I would like to program GRUB2 to have it trigger actions of my choosing.

The [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Vendor-power_002don-keys) mentions I can probably check for an alternative boot key by testing a bit in RTC/CMOS memory, but I cannot identify which bit it is.

Is there a way to detect it?

Answer (score 0):

The information which power button was used is not kept in the CMOS, but in shadow ROM.

Find the string `"LegendKirk4"` within segment 0xF000 (physical address range [0xF0000, 0xFFFFF]).  32 bytes from the start of that string, there is a byte with the value you need.  If the computer was turned on with the normal power button, this byte will be zero.  If the computer was turned on with the Novo button, it will be 15 (0x0f).

It’s not easy to follow the above steps from a GRUB script, though, as GRUB does not provide a ‘search memory’ primitive.  You are pretty much forced to hardcode the address in the config file.  That is, look for the signature by grepping `/dev/mem` from a booted system; then, in the config file, verify the presence of the signature with a couple of `read_dword` commands, after which you can read off the value with `read_byte`.